# Наследование c#

Tags: c#, типы, методы

Господа, попалась вот такая интересная задачка.
Суть задачи состоит в том, что я, не меняя остальной код, должен в методе Main() создать объект типа f и чудесным образом вызвать метод, который находится в классе d. Что я не пробовал, у меня вызывается только метод класса e. Может быть, вы на идею подтолкнете? Спасибо.

Вот код:

```
using System;
class a
{
    public int x = 90;
}
class b : a { }
class c : b { }
class d : c
{
    public void Num()
    {
        ((a)this).x = 88;
        Console.WriteLine(1);
    }    
}
class e : d 
{
    public new void Num()
    {
        ((a)this).x = 34;
        Console.WriteLine(2);
    }  
}
class f : e { }
class g
{
    static void Main()
    {
        f F = new f();

    }
}
```

**Обновление**

```
static void Main()
{
    f F = new f();
    d D = F;
    D.Num();
}
```

Как вариант. Но если без приведения типов?

Comment: Это даже не приведение типов, у вас не downcast, а upcast, который не вовсе не генерирует кода и безопасен по определению.

Без upcast'а поможет, например, reflection. Но зачем?

Comment: И можно короче:

    d D = new f();
    D.Num();

Comment: Спасибо, немного прояснилось

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение довольно простое, причем без введения дополнительных переменных:

```
(F as d).Num();
```

Но вообще стоит отметить, что в этой "интересной задачке" понапихана куча совершенно не относящегося к делу кода.

Answer (score 1):

Если следовать жестко условиям, то первый вариант более подходит.

А именно:

```
static void Main()
{
    f F = new f();
    d D = F;
    D.Num();
}
```